# JavaFX: List vs ObservableList performance/memory usage

Tags: performance, memory-management, javafx, observablelist

In the JavaFX doc it says:

> A list that allows listeners to track changes when they occur.

Since the ObservableList can do more, I'm wondering if there is a noticable diffrence in performance or memory usage between these two? (I'm using JavaFX 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no performance (memory leak) differences since ObservableList extends list or map with an observability feature advantage. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/collections/jfxpub-collections.htm)